# Fixed hub threaded

Tags: hub

I recently purchased a pre rad Bike, my friend who is a bike guy found it for me and said it was a good buy. Now when I learnt to skid I was fanging thru traffic non stop loving it, until that is the cog and locking nut came free from the hub after speed checking to go between some traffic a lil scary....

Am pretty sure hub is threaded and need to rebuild the wheel... But if anyone knows why this may have happened I would be stoked as I dont want it to happen again cheers....

I think the"contra" thread is a lil messed up tried to tighten everything up but when I applied back pressure the lock ring popped straight off again sturmey archer hubs I am a bit of a noob can ride but yeah they said it should be unbreakable haha not for me I guess

Comment: I think the"contra" thread is a lil messed up tried to tighten everything up but when I applied back pressure the lock ring popped straight off again sturmey archer hubs I am a bit of a noob can ride but yeah they said it should be unbreakable haha not for me I guess

Comment: What does "pre rad bike" mean?  A photo of the bike and a clloseup of the hub might help clarify your question.   I guess a "contra thread" is a left-hand thread, which is common on the left pedal/crank and on some bottom brackets.  Cassettes and hubs don't generally have left hand threads, but they often need special tools to undo.

Comment: Sorry I am full noob and "E"tarded is NSAnalog frame Carbon bars sturmey archer hubs is all I really Know

Comment: I still am unsure if this is a fixed gear bike, or if your Sturmey Archer hub is a three speed.

Comment: @Criggie it could be both, SA make a 3 speed fixed hub. Or at least they have done, I don't know whether they still do.

Comment: In any case, it doesn't really make all that much of a difference to the answer I think.

Comment: Nah just fixed is a flip flop but no coasting sprocket if that sounds right?

Comment: Some flip flop hubs allow for a fixed cog on both sides. If you have one (you can look up the model, or inspect it to see if it lets you use a lockring),  you can just install a new fixed cog on the other side provided nothing else is wrong with the wheel.  Are you sure you installed the lockring and cog back on properly?

Comment: If it's an aluminium lock ring replace it with steel. They're garbage.

Comment: Fitting a brake would increase the value-for-money of any other investments.

Answer (score 3):

When you have a threaded cog, its designed to tighten when you pedal forward due to the threading direction. So, it doesn't come loose.

When you skid stop or stop by resisting the pedals on a fixie, you apply torque the opposite way on the cog loosening it. The lockring is supposed to prevent this by its threading. But if the lockring is loose, all bets are off. So, you need to make sure that the lockring and cog are tight periodically with a fixie. See [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/13438/fixed-gear-slipping) for some details on how to tighten the cog and lockring properly. You'll need a lockring tool + chain whip.

If when the cog came off you damaged threads or spokes or something somehow, you will need to serivce/replace the wheel.

Comment: Thank you I feel That the thread on the hub is kaput. Is is cheaper to get a new hub and rebuild or purchase a new rim

Comment: @Z_VanZelm try to brake without skidding too - its less stress on you and your bike, and your tyre will not develop flat spots.

Comment: Cheaper and better to get a new wheel typically, unless the rim is worth something and you have a good person to rebuild it with a new hub and spokes.